# When current flow though a straight wire does it create a magnetic dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

When current flow through a wire, this generates a magnetic field around the wire, this field tends to circle around the wire and called electromagnetic field.

When current flow though a straight wire does it create a magnetic dipole ?

If yes, Where are these dipoles (by drawing) ? I didn't see any site draw the dipoles

If no, Why do the spinning of the electrons create a dipole but the flowing of the electrons don't ?

Comment: NoOne, I asked a question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/498923/magnetic-field-induction-from-an-electric-current-through-molten-metal-and-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run current through a wire, a circular magnetic field is created around the wire. It does not have poles but the magnetic field does have a direction (tangent to the circle. Keep in mind you have to use the right hand rule to find the direction).

So it does not create poles

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are talking about a transient flow from one charged region to an oppositely charged region, current can only flow in a loop.
Any loop of current will produce a field that resembles the classical magnetic dipole field at a distance.  Separated electric charges produce an electric dipole field.  Flowing electrons are likely to be randomly oriented, so that their spin dipoles cancel out.

Comment: *"Unless you are talking about a transient flow from one charged region to an oppositely charged region, current can only flow in a loop."* - as a counterexample, consider, for example, a sinusoidally driven, end fed antenna.

Comment: R.W.Bird Agree with you. And the comment from Alfred is substantial. The quintessence is that accelerated (accelerated, decelerated or moved in circles) electrons induce a magnetic field. To me, the switch-on of a current lead to the alignment of the electrons magnetic dipoles and after the self-holding (self-inductance) lead to the magnetic field around a wire with DC-flow of electrons. Was ever observed a magnetic field for currents through a melted metal and what is the magnetic field of an electron beam (deflected only by electric fields)?